# How to fetch github releases using bitbake recipe?

Tags: github, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe, github-release

I am trying to fetch a github latest release from a recipe(bitbake) using yocto build system.

My recipe looks like this...

```
DESCRIPTION = "web based app "
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

APP_DESTINATION = "${libdir}/App"
SRC_URI = " \
    https://github.com/User/App/releases/download/latest/App.zip;github_private_asset=1 \
   "

S = "${WORKDIR}"


do_install_append() {
         install -d ${D}${APP_DESTINATION}
         cp -r ${S}/App/* ${D}${APP_DESTINATION}
   
}

FILES_${PN} += "\
    ${APP_DESTINATION}/* \
"
```

but it says..

```
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 170.72.121.4
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|170.72.121.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-10-04 07:10:36 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Can someone please help how to fetch the releases?

Comment: so... your system has a connection issue?

Comment: No, every other recipe works fine. only releases doesnt work

Comment: but the URI returns "not found"

Comment: thats what confuses me too.

Comment: but i checked the url from browser as well. it is working fine. only problem is with bitbake

Comment: 404 means that the bitbake fetcher is not able to reach the release uri, but that doesnt mean if its a problem with the internet or the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Run only this recipe with bitbake with option -vDDD and you will see more, much more :)

Comment: Thank you Lubo. i found out that as bitbake uses  wget to fetch from https url and it uses --header="Authorization: token to authorize and as i am not providing this header in this recipe thats why it is 404.

Comment: do you know how can we fetch the release via ssh? or how can we put this header in the recipe?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new fetch mode in Yocto which is available from [`github-releases.bbclass`](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/mickledore/meta/classes-recipe/github-releases.bbclass). It is designed to fetch the release source from public GitHub https artifact.

Try to use `inherit github-releases` and `GITHUB_BASE_URI`. Also there is a [libusb1 recipe](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/5d060725e706476751b0bda8e6d9f3670aa4b7de/meta/recipes-support/libusb/libusb1_1.0.26.bb#L18) which uses same fetching, it can help a lot.